# Is it safe to enter username and password in plain text in express.js?

Tags: azure, express, tedious

I'm trying to connect to Azure SQL Server from Node.js and express.js. I'm going through this tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-nodejs?tabs=windows) which shows that we enter the username and password to the sql server. Is this safe? After we deploy the app, express.js which contains these information also gets deployed to the web-server (Azure). Would this then be visible to others?

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial is to help you understand how to connect to a SQL Server database. This is not intended to be used in production as is. A better option would be to put those in config settings or environment variables. Then reference the values in the code. That way you do not have your username and password hard coded into the code and can easily change the values between different environments (develop, production...).

If you use environment variables, you would reference `process.env.USERNAME` and `process.env.PASSWORD`, for example.

Comment: That's very helpful. Thank you. Just out of curiosity, if I enter my username and password in the environment variable, that's more secure? Azure still moves all files during deployment. Is it still safe?

Comment: It will remove your username and password from being in the code and in repository which will reduce one place the username and password can be compromised. It will not make it harder for an attacker crack the password.

Comment: Got it. So, is there a better way to do this? Any material you can point me to so that I can learn and understand it more?

Comment: Another way would be to use an Azure Managed Identity. This discusses how to set it up and access with .NET code, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi. Here is a link talking about the Azure Identity package for javascript which should be what you need to use the managed identity https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-node-latest